# Does specifying "http://" or "https://" eliminate risk of attacks in user-input links?

Tags: html, html-parsing

I want to allow users to make links in my web app that other users can see.  I don't want them to be able to run any javascript or xss or anything, of course.  Does a simple "http://" at the beginning eliminate those problems?  That is, if an href starts with "http://", can I let my users click it without worrying too much?

Comment: If it was that easy... also http links could contain malicious javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you escape html tags and quotes in the links they post, there won't be any problem. 
Obviously, if a site contains a reflected xss, such as `http://example.com/?x=<script>...</script>` and such a link is posted, you can't avoid the xss if the page they're redirected to is xss vulnerable.